# Linear Bonding curve price for a given supply (P(S) = S) and Price of a trade (1/2*S^2))

Tags: solidity, bonding-curves

My question is about the relationship between the equation that represents the price change with the supply in a linear bonding curve ((P(S) = S)) and the integral function of the linear bonding curve equation that gives us the price of a trade. I am seeking clarification on why there are two equations and how they relate to each other.

My understanding is In a linear bonding curve where ( P(S) = S ), the price of a trade can be calculated using the concept of the reserve function, which represents the area under the curve up to a certain point. Here's why:

1. **Linear Bonding Curve Equation**: In this case, the bonding curve equation is ( P(S) = S ), where ( P ) represents the price and ( S ) represents the total supply of tokens. This means that the price increases linearly with the total supply.
2. **Reserve Function**: The reserve function represents the area under the bonding curve up to a certain supply level. Since the bonding curve is linear, the area under the curve can be calculated using the formula for the area of a triangle: 1/2 * S^2 In this case, the base is the total supply S and the height is the price S. So, the reserve function (R(S)) can be calculated as (R(S) = 1/2 S^2 )
3. **Cost of Trade**: When you make a trade (buy or sell) at a certain supply level, you're essentially changing the total supply of tokens. The difference between the reserve function values before and after the trade represents the total value paid or received for that trade. This is because the reserve function gives us the total value of tokens up to a certain supply level.

So, to compute the cost of any trade, you calculate the reserve function value before the trade and after the trade, and then subtract the two values. This gives you the difference in the reserve, which corresponds to the total value paid or received for the trade.

My question is If Alice wants to mint 1 Bonding curve token when the Total Supply is Zero. She will need to pay 0.5 ETH and not 1.
It is confusing that Price = total_supply (totalCost n(n+1)/2) and area undercover is the actual cost (n^2/2). I don't understand why are area under the curve or reserve integral function gives that actual cost of trade. This [article](https://medium.com/aventus/token-bonding-curves-683b8b309c18) explains it a bit but it is still not clear.